# How do I load an executable into IDA without it correcting relocatable references?

Tags: ida

I am working with a dumped program, and I essentially want to load it into IDA without performing any (relocation) address fixups. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried the following without success:
1. Manually loading it, and choosing *not* to load the .reloc section
2. Rebasing the image base to zero

Comment: Maybe load it as a binary file,  and then split into segments using a bit of .py or .idc script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I chose a load address manually, IDA would offset these references by whatever address I chose. If I didn't choose a load address manually, then IDA wouldn't change those references, so then all I needed to do was rebase the program *without* performing fixups.

Answer (score 2):

[environment variable `IDA_NORELOC`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1375.shtml) might work.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the ".reloc" section, if IDA can't find it, it can't relocate the image.